# GWT Celltable resize

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I'm developing an application using GWT. I'm using celltable to
display dynamic values from database (based on a query). I have
following queries:

Assume: I have set the table height as 100px. I have placed the table
in a scrollpanel.

1. Now, My query returns 20rows, which are more than 100px, I want the
   table to resize to fit all the 20rows. which inturn would cause the
   scrollpanel to resize, which inturn should resize the parent of the
   scrollpanel. First of all, I would like to know if this is possible at
   all? If so, how?

I have tried these:
 I thought, by obtaining the tables new and old height, I could resize
by calling setHeight() and for the parent's height, by
getParent().setHeight(). However, I was stupid to think this way as
I'm setting the value of the height for the table to be 100px. As this
is static, it would print the same value for old and new height and
would change nothing.

Any ideas of how to proceed with this??

P.S: I'm using GWT2.3

Comment: Why are you setting the height of the cellTable to 100px at the beginning?

Comment: If we don't set a value for the height, would it not be null?

Comment: No, it will resize depending on the number of rows, and available space.

Comment: Thanks for that..It will resize. However only the cellTable resizes based on no.of rows ie. if during a search it returns 20rows, and i search again which returns only 2rows, the rows resizes.. But not the table. I want the widget holding the table to expand/shrink(resize) based on row count. For instance, if a table has 20rows, I want the window height to be increased and if the table has 2rows, it should be shrinked to appropriate height. Any ideas for this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sure that you're not setting a fixed size for the celltable containers?

The containers will shrink, expand with the celltable, but they also need to not have their height set (the height defaults to auto - which is the behavior that you need).

Comment: Perfect! I got where I went wrong. I was using a Layoutpanel which had to have initial height. So, that forbids the celltable to increase its height. I've replaced the layoutpanel with an absolutepanel and things are working as expected. Thanks alot Jonic!